# Make BooleanField display a larger checkbox in Django

Tags: django, checkbox, resize, boolean, field

So I am creating a website using Django templates, forms etc. One thing I've noticed though is that the checkboxes I create via BooleanFields are too small. Any idea how to make the thing bigger?

Comment: `BooleanField` does not "create" any checkboxes. It's just usual `<input type="checkbox" />` and you should style it with CSS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try doing this using css, but the thing is very difficult: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/

When you create a class in css you can add it to your input using widgets, something like:

```
field = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'your_class'}))
```

Answer (score 4):

I found below is easier and works for me:

```
class Meta:
        ...
        widgets = {
            'my_checkbox': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'style':'width:20px;height:20px;'}),
        }
```